# LINQ expression to check if field contains string

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

I have this code

```
private List<Autocomplete> _GetPeople(string query)
{
    List<Autocomplete> people = new List<Autocomplete>();
    var results = (from p in db.People
             where (p.FirstName + " " + p.LastName).Contains(query)
                   orderby p.FirstName, p.LastName
                         select p).Take(10).ToList();
}
```

I would like to know how to write something equivalent in this format

```
 private ApplicationDbContext _dbContext;
    public PeopleController()
    {
        _dbContext = new ApplicationDbContext();
    }

    var result=_dbContext.people.where(p=>   ...... ).contains()...
```

How can I do it? Thanks.

**update** I wrote some code by myself but is not working.Seems that I can not use a where with || to use double condition

```
 var result = _dbContext.people;
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(query)) result = result.Where(a => a.Name.Contains(query) || a.LastName.Contains(query));
```

Comment: `_dbContext.people.Where(p => (p.FirstName + " " + p.LastName).Contains(query)).OrderBy(p => new { p.FirstName, p.LastName }).Take(10)` - I'm not sure Linq to Entities would be able to translate it to SQL though (due to the `FirstName` + `LastName` concatenation).

Comment: This question is unclear (to me). What _exactly_ do you want to do? Change _query syntax_ to _method syntax_? What's wrong with your code?

Comment: Your `Where` clause is `(p.FirstName + " " + p.LastName).Contains(query)`.  That's not what you typed in the second snippet. The two snippets should be equivalent anyway resulting in a `LIKE '%something%` query that performs badly

Comment: Are you trying to change the results or just go from query syntax to method syntax?

Comment: hello thanks for your fast responses, I am trying to go from query syntax to method syntax

Comment: I have updated the code

Comment: Why do you want to check the concatenated string? Check for "is it in firstname" or "is it in lastname" does the job

Comment: how can I do it @scholonzo? I am working with typeahead and I need something like an authocomplete

Comment: @schlonzo: Not necessarily. If the user types "John Sm" then it would only match a John Smith if you concatenated this way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your comments, it sounds like you want to convert to method syntax. Personally, I find LINQ syntax easier to read and write. But method syntax should look something like this:

```
var results = db.People
                .Where(p => (p.FirstName + " " + p.LastName).Contains(query))
                .Orderby(p => p.FirstName)
                .ThenBy(p => p.LastName)
                .Take(10)
                .ToList();
```

Comment: thanks a lot!!! I just started using syntax in my project and wanted to keep syntax in all the project. thanks again